# How to make one field editable in a form field using kendo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am learning kendo and trying to understand it. I have created an edit page where any page you want to edit will go to this particular page. The status field is the condition place where if it is resolved the entire form field is disabled. But I want to change that, I want to make one particular form field to be enabled where the rest is still disabled, how do I do that?

```
                            {
                            field: "Status",
                            label: "Status: ",
                            editor: "DropDownList",
                            editorOptions: {
                                optionLabel: "Please select Status",
                                dataTextField: "text",
                                dataValueField: "value",
                                dataSource: [
                                    { text: "NEW", value: "NEW" },
                                    { text: "RESOLVED", value: "RESOLVED" },
                                    { text: "CLOSED", value: "CLOSED" }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
```

this is the particular field that I want to be editable,

```
                if ($("#Status").val() == "RESOLVED") {
                $(".nav-link:contains(List of Resolved Issue)").addClass("active").removeClass("text-light").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(darkgray, grey)");
                $(".k-form-field").addClass("k-state-disabled");
                $(".k-buttons-end").hide();
            }
```

this is the one function placed where it makes the entire form field to be disabled, I want to make the status field only to be enabled and the rest disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one could answer, I had to ask my senior and turns out it was very simple. Only one line needed to be added:

```
if ($("#Status").val() == "RESOLVED") {
                $(".nav-link:contains(List of Resolved Issue)").addClass("active").removeClass("text-light").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(darkgray, grey)");
                $(".k-form-field").addClass("k-state-disabled");
                $("#Status").parents(".k-form-field.k-state-disabled").removeClass("k-state-disabled"); //search parents with related classes & remove "disabled" class
                $(".k-buttons-end").hide();
```

Thats it. The entire form field is still disabled except for the Status field.